# Migrating mysql 5 million rows to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: ssis, migration

I have read all the answers from this site and I have a way forward but is there a better solution to the below.

I use SSIS migrate from MySQL to SQL Server, one particular table has 5 million rows which is roughly 10gb of data and it takes 4.5 hours. The table has 3 columns - an INT PK. Date time and nvarchar column.

SQL Server 2016 is on a 2 core, 16gb ram machine. SQL Server is limited to 8gb of RAM. Tempdb is split to 4 files. Destination database is in simple mode. Growth rate set to 250mb.

I installed MySQL on the same box to avoid network latency.

**Package 1**

Migrate from MySQL to SQL Server. With destination don't check constraints. Dropped destination indexes. Commit size 10k rows per batch. SQL Server destination connector rather then OLE DB.

Takes 4.5 hours. With or without a pk on destination only saves 10 minutes.

**Package 2**

Same as above with a full cache look up to migrate delta rows. I modified the generated SQL to look up the ID column only, as well as under the advance tab but it Failed with an error code. Assuming this was due to full look up cache not fitting in memory. Changed to no cache. But it still took an age as I can see in profile trace it still needed the work time to check and insert.. Same when I removed the lookup and tried a merge join

**Package 3**

Same as package 1 but with the ADO.NET source connector; I do a where clause on last migrated PK. This now takes minutes to migrate the delta but I still need to pre migrate the data.

Package 3 is the best I can do. Any other ideas?

Comment: When you run these packages, are you executing from Visual Studio SSDT or are you running the packages from the command line/SQL Agent job? The reason I ask is that the debugger, the visual interface into SSIS packages, has an appreciable drag on performance

Comment: Take package 1, remove the destination. Run it. This will baseline how long it takes to extract your data from MySQL and thus, your theoretical maximum throughput.

Comment: You have a three columned table consisting columns: int, datetime and nvarchar which means each row is (4+8+2+2*?) bytes with a max size of ...40 gigs if everything was 4000 characters, but let's check something - Double click the line between your source and your destination in SSIS and in the Meatadata properties window, what data type is listed for the nvarchar column?

Comment: Thank you . Yeah I guess the problem is I dont know where the bottle neck is. Whether if its reading the source or the bulk inserts. I'm building it on my PC visual studio business tool. Compile it . Then copy over the DTSX file. Then created a SQL agent job to run the job. Ok I will benchmark the reading of the source. Can I remove the destination and run the DTSX on UAT bearing in mind customer environment does not have visual studio

Comment: Copy paste the package 1 as Package1NoDestination and run that to establish your extract only benchmark.

Comment: Package 2 - the lookup stuff you'll likely want full cache. When it starts up, the cache will fill with data from the reference. Otherwise, you're going to fire off a query against the target table for every row that flows through the data flow aka 5M queries.